Any normal set in $\mathbb{N}$ contains infinitely many perfect squares.
We know that a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ is normal if $1_{A}(n)$ is a normal sequence in base $2$. And since $A$ is normal, it has natural density $1/2$. Then according to Szemeredi's Theorem, it contains arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions. And since if an arithmetic progression sequence contains a perfect square, it contains infinitely many perfect squares, this implies that $A$ contains infinitely many perfect squares. Is my proof correct?

containing arbitrarily long AP's doesn't guarantee you have any perfect squares. EG Take the AP's of common difference 1, of the form $\cup [k^2 + 1, k^2 + 2k ] $. You have natural density 1, with no perfect squares.

@CalvinLin Wait so is this set a counterexample of the statement in the title then? I feel like it's hard to construct a normal set from scratch.

I would have thought "arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions" would each be of finite length.

@Henry Yeah i think you are correct. My argumennt is wrong.

My set isn't a counterexample as it has a natural density of 1. My guess ) is that taking any normal sequence and removing a set of natural density 0 (in this case the squares) would still result in a normal sequence, but I'm not too familiar with normal numbers to say that with certainty.

@CalvinLin yeah i think i understand your idea. I'm trying to figure out how to show it using the limit definiton rigorously.
